# Trying to set HTML/CSS table to fit mobile screens - not working

Tags: html, css

I have several tables that I am trying to make responsive so that the table and it's contents shrink to the width of the device. Below is an example of the code so far.

```
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="1" class="toptable;" style="border:none;width:100%;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style type="text/css">*
```

Is anyone able to tell me why the `@media` query isn't working for me?

Comment: write meta tag in header

Comment: 1) you're meta tag should be in the `<head></head>` 2) don't use inline css. This has the highest specificity value, thus without the use of !important - the styles won't be overriden. 3) where's your media query? 4) your style tags, should also be in the `<head>` element - or much better, as an external stylesheet

Comment: `"toptable;"` is hardly a proper class name; you'd have to work very hard to match that with css. Most likely you meant `"toptable"` without a semicolon.

Comment: Sorry, relatively new to this! I've amended based on the feedback- am I right in saying I don't need to use @media query? If so then why doesn't this code now work?

Comment: <head>
<table class="toptable">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="right"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <style type="text/css">* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toptable {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Just change the place of that.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Bootstrap. Bootstrap provides a 12-column grid, and one of the primary advantages of bootstrap is that web-pages made using this 12-column grid are responsive and hence adjust to different screen sizes pretty neatly.

You can download bootstrap from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/).